# WebControl.CssClass vs WebControl.Attributes["class"]

Tags: asp.net, css, web-controls

What is the difference between the two methods of setting the css class on web control?
How they are synchronized? If I add class to `CssClass` and `Attributes["class"]`, how it will be rendered?

Comment: You could always try it... Would have thought that all CSSClass would do is inspect / amend the Attributes["class"] anyway - that's how I would have done it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They both will be rendered the same.

As a `class="myClass"` in html.

The property `CssClass`, if set, will take precedence and overwrite the `Attributes["class"]`.

Answer (score 0):

But Keep in mind: if you want to check if your WebControl has "myClass" assigned, you have to look in CssClass AND in the AttributeCollection. (and you have to check with contains because there can be more CssClasses in the string.)